# Password Protect a Directory with .htaccess and .htpasswd with Rewrite Rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to except a protected directory. In the root-directory a have this exception for rewrite rule

```
##-- xdumpx
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} xdumpx
RewriteRule ^xdumpx/(.*)$ xdumpx/$1 [QSA,L]
```

It works fine as long as I don't have a passwort protection in the directory xdumpx.

The .htaccess file in the xdumpx directory looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine off
</IfModule>
AuthName "MySQLDumper"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/var/www/xxx/html/xdumpx/.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

If I delete this part

```
AuthName "MySQLDumper"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/var/www/xxx/html/xdumpx/.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

it works fine again. 
Where is the problem with the password protection?